# TFS2010 Build Controllers

Tags: team-foundation-server

As I know, In TFS2010, One Build Controller serves One Project Collection. And, ideally one build server should have One build controller into it.

However, as per the link below-

http://marknic.com/2010/05/14/MultipleTFS2010BuildControllersOnASingleBuildBox.aspx we can install mutiple build controller in a single build box.

Can two or more build controller can run at a same time.

Because the link suggests that, we need to switch between controllers ....

Is it that, we can use one controller at a time.

Answer (score 1):

According to this author:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/04/13/configuring-multiple-tfs-build-services-on-one-machine.aspx

...it sounds like you can. Except that, according to him:

> If you want to run builds on both
>   Build Service instances concurrently,
>   you’ll want to take steps to prevent
>   resource contention like moving the
>   working directories for the Agent on
>   one of the instances to a separate
>   hard disk. Even then you may encounter
>   serious performance degradation if two
>   instances of MSTest are invoked at the
>   same time.